# Ruby regex matching overlapping terms

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using:

```
r = /(hell|hello)/

"hello".scan(r)  #=>   ["hell"]
```

but I would like to get `[ "hell", "hello" ]`.

http://rubular.com/r/IxdPKYSUAu

Comment: Either scan it twice, or figure out which strings contain each other and compute matches yourself after checking for only the longest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a fancier capture:

```
'hello'.match(/((hell)o)/).captures
=> ["hello", "hell"]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, regexes don't work like that. But you can do something like this:

```
terms = %w{hell hello}.map{|t| /#{t}/}

str = "hello"

matches = terms.map{|t| str.scan t}

puts matches.flatten.inspect # => ["hell", "hello"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always take out common subexpression. I.e., the following works:

```
r = /hello{0,1}/

"hello".scan(r)  #=>   ["hello"]
"hell".scan(r)   #=>   ["hell"]
```

Comment: Or use the simpler `/hello?/`

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
r = /(hell|(?<=hell)o)/

"hello".scan(r)  #=>   ["hell","o"]
```

It won't give you `["hell", "hello"]`, but rather `["hell", "o"]`